# how to get "xpath" from xml node in C#

Tags: c#, xml

xml example:

```
<Details name="Tee">
    <Surname id="Kat"/>
    <MiddleName id="TeeKat"/>
</Details>
```

Given attribute @id:

I want to get the following paths:

```
Details.Surname.@id=Kat
Details.Surname.@id=TeeKat
```

Code I have so far:

```
private static object GetXmlPath(XmlNode node) {
  if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute) {
     return String.Format("{0}@{1}", GetXmlPath(((XmlAttribute)node).OwnerElement), node.Name);
  }
  return node.ParentNode == null ? "" : String.Format("{0}{1}.", GetXmlPath(node.ParentNode), node.Name);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the paths, given an attribute"? Identify all occurrences of an attribute `id` in an XML file?

Comment: Those don't look like XPath expressions to me.  Which is fine if that's what you want to generate, but don't call it XPath if it isn't XPath.

Comment: Okay sorry about that, but i want to generate something like this

Comment: So what don't you like about your current implementation, which seems to do what you want?  you just want the =[value] bit?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems largely to do what you want, to add in the values:

```
private static object GetXmlPath(XmlNode node) {
  if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute) {
     return String.Format("{0}@{1}={2}", GetXmlPath(((XmlAttribute)node).OwnerElement), node.Name, node.Value);
  }
  return node.ParentNode == null ? "" : String.Format("{0}{1}.", GetXmlPath(node.ParentNode), node.Name);
}
```

I would strongly suggest you actually go for /Details/Surname/@id=Kat for something that is more naturally readable, and **because . is legal in XmlNames**

ie:

```
private static object GetXmlPath(XmlNode node) {
  if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute) {
     return String.Format("{0}@{1}={2}", GetXmlPath(((XmlAttribute)node).OwnerElement), node.Name, node.Value);
  }
  return node.ParentNode == null ? "/" : String.Format("{0}{1}/", GetXmlPath(node.ParentNode), node.Name);
}
```

returning /Details/MiddleName/@id=TeeKat etc